# Changing checkboxes to a radio button group ExtJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I am brand new to `Ext JS`. I have this group of checkboxes that work fine but I need to change them to `Radio` buttons and retain their functionality. If you could help me out I would appreciate it. Again I am brand new to EXT JS. I made them `field.Radio` but still allows all of them to be selected. Please help:

```
var employeeBox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Radio', {
         id:'employeeBox',
             fieldLabel: 'Employee Group:',
           labelAlign:'left'
         });


       var mpBox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Radio', {
         id:'mpBox',
             fieldLabel: 'Market Particpants Group:',
           labelAlign:'left'
         });


       var committeeBox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Radio', {
         id:'committeeBox',
             fieldLabel: 'Committee Group:',
           labelAlign:'left'
         });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the same name to all of them. For example:

```
   var employeeBox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Radio', {
         id:'employeeBox',
         name: 'group',
         fieldLabel: 'Employee Group:',
         labelAlign:'left'
   });


   var mpBox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Radio', {
         id:'mpBox',
         name: 'group',
         fieldLabel: 'Market Particpants Group:',
         labelAlign:'left'
   });


   var committeeBox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Radio', {
        id:'committeeBox',
        name: 'group',
        fieldLabel: 'Committee Group:',
        labelAlign:'left'
   });
```

Comment: So simple yet so frustrating. Thanks!